# Move a GMSPolyline in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a requirement that in some cases a GMSPolyline be moved from one location to another. Here is the scenario:

1. A user opens a GMSMapView and creates a GMSPolyline feature.
2. Then the user changes the map position
3. The user taps a button to center the newly created polyline in the new view position, that is, the newly created line feature is moved to the center of the new camera view.

So far I can find no resources for how to do this. There are plenty of examples for creating and editing GMSPolyline features, but not finding one for moving the entire feature. Can anyone point me to an example for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to move the polyline? Looks like you just want to move the GMSCamera in a way that the polyline is in center. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, when the camera position changes, I want to move the entire GMSPolyline to the center of the new camera view

Comment: GMSPolyline is based on the coordinates you feed to it, so I guess there is no way you can change its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the coordinates of all the locations that make the GSMPath that is the base of your GMSPolyline. For each location you can calculate the new point using [GMSGeometryOffset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils.html#ga8d6fb874513718f8325ebca9615b051e), then you draw a new polyline.

Or you can use [-(instancetype) pathOffsetByLatitude:longitude:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_path.html#a36243cf79d6cd8565e0e4337e921e97c) of GMSPath on the GMSPath that describes your polyline.

You use one or the other according the data that you have available (as an example the start and end target of the GMSCameraPosition after a pan)